# Strength of tides induced by the Earth on the Moon to Moon on the Earth calculation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, gravity

In my astrophysics problem sheet I have to compare the strength of tides induced by the Earth on the Moon to that induced by the Moon
on the Earth.

This is my attempt:

$$F_\text{grav}=\frac{GM_\text{Earth}m_\text{Moon}}{d^2}$$
where d is the distance between their CoM's.

\begin{align}
F_\text{tidal}&=\frac{dF_\text{grav}}{dr}\Delta r\\
&=-2\frac{GM_\text{Earth}m_\text{Moon}}{d^3}\Delta r
\end{align}
So, 
$$\frac{F_\text{tidal,Earth}}{F_\text{tidal,Moon}}=\frac{-2\frac{GM_\text{Earth}m_\text{Moon}}{d^3}\Delta r_\text{Earth}}{-2\frac{GM_\text{Earth}m_\text{Moon}}{d^3}\Delta r_\text{Moon}}=\frac{\Delta r_{Earth}}{\Delta r_{Moon}}=\frac{2 r_\text{Earth}}{2 r_\text{Moon}}=\frac{ r_\text{Earth}}{ r_\text{Moon}}.$$

In the solution it was given however

$$\frac{F_\text{tidal,Earth}}{F_\text{tidal,Moon}}=\frac{M_\text{Earth}r_\text{moon}}{M_\text{moon}r_\text{Earth}}$$

Why does the mass of the planets feature in this calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your $F_{grav}$ is not what is needed; your is the attraction between Earth and Moon, while instead for the tides on Earth the force is applied to the water, or to the test mass you use to measure the tide (not to the whole Earth). So you have, on Earth:

$F_E = -\frac{G M_{Moon}M_{test mass}}{r^2}$

The test mass disappear when calculating the ratio, on one side you have the Moon pulling Earth's water, on the other, Earth pulling Moon's water.